# "No overloads match this call" errors from Typescript (strict) while using .map to add and remove event listeners. Although my code works

Tags: typescript

```
    focusElements &&
         focusElements.forEach((item) => {
         item.removeEventListener('keydown', focusFunc);
         item.addEventListener('keydown', focusFunc);
         return true;
        });
    
    const focusFunc = (evt: KeyboardEvent) => {
     ...does focus stuff
     }
```

*This is the error message*
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(type: keyof ElementEventMap, listener: (this: Element, ev: Event) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type '"keydown"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof ElementEventMap'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(evt: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
Type '(evt: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
Types of parameters 'evt' and 'evt' are incompatible.
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': altKey, charCode, code, ctrlKey, and 17 more.ts(2769)

Comment: This was answered correctly [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72033238/typescript-addeventlistener-to-keydown-giving-error)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.